# Indexing Bixby Spoken-Summary

Tags: bixby

I received help on getting Bixby to read the list in the view, but now I am trying to have it be useful for Hands-Free List Navigation. Is there a way use indexing in Spoken-Summary? Currently it just reads each item in the list, but it will be difficult to use ordinal selection without indexing.

Comment: I know the for-each has an option for index-var, but I do not see an option for where-each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed `where-each` does not have child-key `index-var`. You can add an index property in the concept structure and add index value in your JS file as a workaround.

However, I would think the speech itself should be sufficient in selecting content. In case of **read-one** Bixby will pause after each item waiting for "next" or "yes". In case of **read-many** developer can set page size.

You can (maybe should) implement your capsule that it takes the content rather than number.

For example: "watch news" --> "which of the following channel would you like" --> "BBC, NBC, CNN, FOX", at the input prompt, rather than auto answer machine, "press 1 for BBC, press 2 for NBC... ", user should be able to say "CNN" or "CNN News" and it will match as an input.

In case you really need index, the current possible work around is to add index as part of the structure in your JS function returning the list. It should not be hard. The voice command of "first", "second"... "last" are built-in features and should work.

You can also go to [developer center](https://support.bixbydevelopers.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/360000183273-Feature-Requests) and make a feature request to add `index-var` to `where-each`, but it will be a PM decision to approve or when to implement such feature.

Comment: I am going by the documentation in the developer site. As far as hands-free navigation goes, the only selection response is the 'ordinal selection', such as "first", "second", etc. I have a list that will be different depending on the user's account they log in to. I could take the user's speech and match it to the name of the item in the list, but the name of the item in the list can be words that are not recognizable by bixby.